# Asking for location permission, grantResults is empty

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, android-permissions

I'm having some trouble asking for the location permission. The activity extends AppCompatActivity

This is the request

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
    arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), LOCATION_PERMISSION_RC)

    return
}
```

And this is how I check the response

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    if (requestCode == LOCATION_PERMISSION_RC) {
        if (grantResults.isNotEmpty()) {
            if ( grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
                // permission was granted
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                setUpMap()
                startLocationUpdates()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "grantResults is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

What happens is that if I grant the permission, the app shows the toast message where it says that grantArray is empty, but the permission has been actually granted, I can use MyLocation layer.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[])):

> `grantResults` - `int`: The grant results for the corresponding permissions which is either `PERMISSION_GRANTED` or `PERMISSION_DENIED`. Never `null`.

while I get an empty array.

This is not really a problem since it would be enough to remove the toast, but I want to understand why that happens and how to fix this behaviour.

EDIT:

I've put some more debugging lines, a log message inside each `if` statement and one as first instruction inside `onRequestPermissionsResult()`, I've found out that as the activity containing the map is started, `onRequestPermissionsResult()` is called and `grantResults` is empty, as it should because I've not yet granted or denied the permission. Now as I tap on `Allow` the function `onRequestPermissionsResult()` is called a second time and in this case the message `Permission granted` is shown.

The new doubt is: is it normal that the function `onRequestPermissionsResult()` is called just as the activity starts? Does `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission()` fires `onRequestPermissionsResult()` checking for the permission?

Comment: `.isNotEmpty()` a function of `kt` ?? or your `custom function` . PS. i code in java .

Comment: It is a kt function which is the equivalent of `if( grantResults.size() > 0)`

Comment: where did you put the first debug dot ?? is it on checkSelfPermission??

Comment: I put all the log inside onRequestPermissionsResult()

Comment: debug using red dots..you can understand the flow correctly..!!

Comment: `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission` this doesnt trigger onRequestPermissionsResult .

Answer (score 1):

I think that your permission request is canceled with some reason.

> // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
>   https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#handle-response